# Upload image to Microsoft Azure Blob storage in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I want to upload images to Microsoft Azure Blob storage. I have created Microsoft Azure account and Blob storage. I have referred https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-azure-blob-service

When calling `this.blob.upload(this.config);` I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined at
>   file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js

my code in ts

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController,public blob: BlobService, public http: Http,private global: globalVariable) {
    const Config: UploadParams = {
      sas: 'https://aptestblob.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2017-04-17&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2017-12-06T03:00:34Z&st=2017-12-05T19:00:34Z&spr=https&sig=fG0RSjIlL3pqY86IPfWZzHpinoU5ziBtY0hSgH7BU9g%3D',
      storageAccount: 'aptestblob',
      containerName: 'aptestblob-container'
    };

    this.test.push(Config);

    var that=this;
    this.imagePath="file:///data/user/0/com.APEHS_ImageUpload/cache/tmp_IMG_20171003_1526141188888569.jpg";
    this.imageBase="tmp_IMG_20171003_1526141188888569.jpg";

    console.log('this.test '+JSON.stringify(this.test));
    console.log('this.imagePath '+this.imagePath);
    console.log('this.imageBase '+that.imageBase);
    if (this.imagePath != "" && this.imagePath != null && this.imagePath != undefined && this.imagePath != 'undefined') {
      const baseUrl = this.blob.generateBlobUrl(Config, that.imageBase);
      console.log('baseUrl '+baseUrl);
      var config = {
        baseUrl: baseUrl,
        sasToken: Config.sas,
        file: this.imagePath,
        complete: () => {
          console.log('Transfer completed !');
        },
        error: () => {
          console.log('Error !');
        },

      };
      console.log('config '+JSON.stringify(config));
      this.blob.upload(config);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used ?

Comment: i am using ionic 3 framework

Comment: after checking the Angular-azure-blob-service on github. I think the type of file in config is a File object and not a string.

Comment: also getting AuthenticationFailed error when i check sas url <Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:77cfdc08-001e-008a-7d78-6e9f17000000 Time:2017-12-06T09:53:06.9187611Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Tue, 05 Dec 2017 19:00:34 GMT] - Expiry [Wed, 06 Dec 2017 03:00:34 GMT] - Current [Wed, 06 Dec 2017 09:53:06 GMT]
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>

Comment: That's because the SAS is only valid for a period of time. Generate another SAS in the azure portal and make sure to make the expiration date later than the current date.